# Perform Math between two CSV files and output as new CSV file (Or print largest difference)

Tags: powershell, script, csv

I have two CSV files with the FileCount and Foldersize of the same folders, taken at different times. (Same headings, same rows and columns. The only difference between these two files is the filecount and folder size values)

I need to compare the two, and report on the subfolders with the largest change in filecount, and the largest change in foldersize.

extract of CSV's below.

CSV1

```
Directory         FileCount   FolderSize
D:\test\Documents   61         18.75
D:\test\Media       61         67,488.43
D:\test\Photos      53         7.88
```

CSV2

```
Directory         FileCount   FolderSize
D:\test\Documents   61        18.75
D:\test\Media       59        62,192.40
D:\test\Photos      32        6.51
```

So far I have the below, but it's outputting an exact copy of CSV1, without making the changes I have in the do loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
#Importing CSV files
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path D:\test\folderstat1.csv
$CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path D:\test\folderstat2.csv

#Setting counts for do loop
$end     = $csv1.Count
$count   = 0

#Set $csv1 Filecount and foldersize to the difference between the row in CSV1 #and CSV2
do{
$csv1.filecount[$count] = $csv1.filecount[$count] - $csv2.filecount[$count]
$csv1.FolderSize[$count] = $csv1.FolderSize[$count] - $csv2.FolderSize[$count]
    $count++
}until($count -eq $end)

$CSV1 | export-csv D:\test\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are placing the index wrongly. Try:

```
$csv1[$count].filecount -= $csv2[$count].filecount
$csv1[$count].FolderSize-= $csv2[$count].FolderSize
```

Or create a new CSV3

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\01\SU_1327671.ps1
#Importing CSV files
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path "D:\test\folderstat1.csv"
$CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path "D:\test\folderstat2.csv"
#Setting counts for do loop
$end     = $csv1.Count
$count   = 0

#Set $CSV3 Filecount and foldersize to the difference between the row in CSV1 #and CSV2

$CSV3 = do{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Directory =  $csv1[$count].Directory
        Filecount = ($csv1[$count].filecount  - $csv2[$count].filecount)
        FolderSize= ($csv1[$count].FolderSize - $csv2[$count].FolderSize)
    }
    $count++
} until($count -eq $end)
$CSV3 | Export-Csv "D:\test\out.csv" -NoTypeInformation

"=" * 50

$CSV3 | Sort {[Math]::Abs($_.FolderSize)} -Desc | Select -First 1|
    ForEach{"Largest (absolute) change {0} in {1}" -f $_.FolderSize,$_.Directory}
```

Sample output:

```
> . .\SU_1327671.ps1
==================================================
Largest (absolute) change 5296 in D:\test\Media
```

---

```
> import-csv .\out.csv

Directory         Filecount FolderSize
---------         --------- ----------
D:\test\Documents 0         0
D:\test\Media     2         5296
D:\test\Photos    21        1,37
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! Since I now have differences stored as objects, I should be able to fairly easily print the directories with the largest value in foldersize and filecount in CSV3. 

I know I can get this information with measure-object - but how can I report the directory name instead of the property I'm measuring?

Comment: To answer my question above, The below works for this. 

$maxfolderdif = ($CSV3| measure-object -Property FolderSize -maximum).maximum
@($CSV3| ? { $_.FolderSize -eq $maxfolderdif})[0]


This sets $LargestFolderDif to max foldersize value, and then compares against the array to get the whole object.

Comment: Could the difference also be negative?

Comment: See changed answer using `[Math]::Abs()` to sort the greates difference also when negative.

Comment: Since my answer **was** helpful, don't you think a check mark as answer and/or a vote up would be appropriate?